# Youtube Android API - callingAppVersion cannot be null or empty

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

So within my fragment I put the following code to handle onclickitem of my listview

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ChannelItem c = (ChannelItem) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), PlayerViewActivity.class);
                    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getActivity().getBaseContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
```

I know this isn't the cleanest code and I'm planning on reformating it.  But it works temporarily (I tested it with a test activity before using a YoutubeBaseActivity). Just to clarify there is no problem in this code but it's to illustrate the flow I'm following.

So when the youtube activity starts it executes following class

```
public class PlayerViewActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String VIDEO = "4SK0cUNMnMM";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_player);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
                findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(Api.DEV_KEY, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! "+error.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
    }

}
```

Here's where I can't find any help anywhere

```
youTubeView.initialize(Api.DEV_KEY, this);
```

This line of code keeps throwing the same error over and over again

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: callingAppVersion cannot be null or empty
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ad.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity$a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at view.PlayerViewActivity.onCreate(PlayerViewActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            ... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the version code and version name of your application to the Manifest file, e.g.:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Comment: Do versionCode and versionName have to be in the  Manifest and not in the Gradle?

Comment: In your gradle under the `defaultConfig` add both the `versionCode` and `versionName`